# Large Text File Searching

Tags: xml, database, lucene, indexing, text-parsing

I'm looking for advice, as I haven't had to deal with large file parsing before and would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel if an open source solution already exists. Here's my situation:

I have roughly 200-300 large XML and text files being dropped in a directory by an automated machine process in the lab I work in. This happens on a regular basis. These files can range in size from a few hundred MB to multiple GBs in size. These files are regularly modified (couple times a week) at random intervals where the old file is simply overwritten with the modified one.

I need the ability to search these files and pull out records that match specific criteria. Of the roughly 20-30 million records in the files (combined), we might actually use < 100,000 of them, but we can't tell which ones until they are searched.

My first thought it to setup a sort of regular file processing job that detects updates and processes the files into a database that can be searched. My only concern would be that it would probably get slower and slower to insert and update the records as it got larger and larger.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a method that might be more suitable for my situation? Off the top of my head I was thinking some text searching system like Lucene, but having never used it I'm not positive if it would be anymore useful than a database...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for a few more details. I don't want to get into the actual file formats (it's really boring, trust me), but just imagine it's a bunch of patient details where I need to search several of the details to find records I want to extract. When I find one I want, I need the entire record XML or the entire line in the text file which then gets loaded into a separate database for further access.

Comment: Also, the searching needs to be somewhat quick, I need to be able to find dozens of results in a few seconds or a minute at most. Searching quickly is more important than updating quickly.

Comment: Does your data consist of well-defined (and relatively short) records? Do you need exact matching only or full text search?

Comment: Yeah, relatively short and not complex. I think I would need full text searching.

Comment: Then I'd definitely go for either a RDBMS or a document-based DB like CouchDB (in which each record would be one document). Lucene's power lies in full-text indexing, if you don't need that, it's probably the wrong option.

Comment: Do you have to persist old files, or can you override old information once you get the new stuff at the beginning of the next cycle?

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many options.  Lucene might be an excellent solution - or a poor choice.

The answer is "It depends"...

You haven't given many details of your project's environment or constraints.

In particular: what's the OS, what's the storage media, and, most important, are you using an RDBMS such as DB2 or SQL Server?

If your application was already using DB2, for example, why not exploit it's built-in XML and text search capabilities?

Comment: I actually don't really have anything going as of yet. It's kind of a clean slate. I mostly wanted suggestions on a way to go, or some options to look into. As for database, I think it would probably be either MySQL or PostGreSQL simply based off of what I have access to. As for system, it would most likely be running off of a LAMP style single server system, and probably nothing fancy for storage other than a built in RAID setup.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how specific your queries are. Lucene and Xapian are good examples for indexing.
In general, you should look at indexing methods, not data mining (I retagged your question to this).

A regular database might be too slow, as it needs to ensure ACID properties and optimize for online updates. For your case, a batch update is probably sufficient.

So in essence I recommend to have a look at Xapian or Lucene (I like xapian better), and consider using it for building an index for your data. You would probably not put all your data into the index (to keep it more manageable), but essentially just put a cross-reference into your existing XML files there.

Depending of what your search queries are like, something even much simpler might do the trick. Think of a large low-level btree storing `key->filename,linenumber` references.